# Vue.js binding model convert string to number

Tags: vue.js, type-conversion, model-binding

I have an input binding this:

`v-model: user.settings.filter(item => item.id === 1)[0].value`

The problem is that value is a string and it doesn't work. How can I convert to number?

user variable is a computed property from vuex:

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            user: 'auth/user',
        }),
    },
```

If this variable was in data it would be easy... but in computed property I don't know how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it where it is broken. That means if you get `value` from an api somewhere, you have to fix the api so that it returns a number and not a string. If you get it from the application somewhere, you need to save it as a number and not as a string. If it is calculated dynamically in the Vuex getter, use `parseInt(..)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)) or `parseFloat(..)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)) to parse whatever is in the string as a number. Keep in mind though that if you have nonsense in the string, you can end up with a NaN in that attribute.

Comment: The problem is that value can be a number, string or whatever. Foreach setting I should convert the value to the desired type. The solution has to be use `parseInt(...)` but I don't know how to do it. I can't do that: `v-model: parseInt(user.settings.filter(item => item.id === 1)[0].value)` because it shows syntax error. And in computed properties don't know neither, I updated the question with this info.

Comment: I finally added some logic in the backend to get the correct type of values.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sumurai8, you shouldn't be receiving a type that needs to be mutated from front-end. Although here is an example on how you could do that, by using **.map(Number)**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   testNumber: undefined
  },
  computed: {
    getTestNumber: function() {
      return this.testNumber ? this.testNumber.split(',').map(Number) : null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>String to number:</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="testNumber">
  <p v-html="getTestNumber"></p>
</div>
```

This converts a String of numbers to Numbers. As soon as you add a character it will return with NaN (not-a-number)

Comment: How can do this approach with my computed property user? I updated the question

Comment: a new computed property like convertUser() { return this.user.split(',').map(Number) } below your mapGetters? and reference convertUser where it needs a Number