# Inside v-autocomplete items' values are string, but in v-model is number, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="addressRegion"
  :items="selectLists.regions"
  item-value="key"
  item-text="value"
></v-autocomplete>
```

AddressRegion is number, f.e. 3, but selectLists.regions contains an array with { key: '3', value: 'Region' }. I need somehow to convert the value inside v-model to string. There are lots of selectLists on the page, that's why using computed property with get/set is not the best solution. How can I fix this?

Comment: It may help [**Vue.js binding model convert string to number**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789731/vue-js-binding-model-convert-string-to-number)

Comment: @BattleHawk, I need another workaround, I've mentioned this in the post

Comment: What if you convert your data to a number like `{ key: 3, value: 'Region' }`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a getter in vuex store, where I convert the selectList items' keys to numbers